# How to override a file in vendor directory

Tags: laravel, microsoft-graph-api, overriding, laravel-socialite, vendor

While I'm using socialite providers plugin in Laravel to authenticate with Microsoft O365. But some functions (including the scope) in a file of the plugin is not working properly. So I need to override that file as a solutions to it.

How to override a file in vendor folder ?

I have tried few solutions found here but not worked.

Comment: dont edit files in you vendor. You can include this files in your project and then overriding.

Answer (score 1):

You can override a vendor class at the composer level as below however if it's possible extending will be more right decision.

You have to apply the update on the `composer.json` of your project. It's a sample that overrides to the `PhpExecutableFinder.php` of Symfony framework. In this case, there have to be a file named exactly same under `overrides/symfony/process/` path.

```json
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Symfony\\Component\\Process\\": "overrides/symfony/process/"
    },
    "exclude-from-classmap": [
        "vendor/symfony/process/PhpExecutableFinder.php"
    ],
},
```

Further information about the `autoload` tag please take a look [documentation](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#autoload).

Also, I have just found a well written [post](https://downing.tech/posts/overriding-vendor-classes) related to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of changing the vendor file, you should create your own class that extends from it and add/override whatever you need to your class. Your class will inherit all the functions of the base class